# Safe URL Parameter Validation in ASP

Tags: security, asp-classic, query-string

I found the following function to parse and validate URL parameters being used in legacy ASP:

```
    FOR EACH field IN Request.QueryString
        var_name = field
        var_value = Request.QueryString(field)
        var_value = Replace(var_value, "'", "&#39;")
        var_value = Replace(var_value,"""","&quot;")
        var_value = Replace(var_value, "&", "&")
        var_value = Replace(var_value, "%", "%")
        str = "Dim " & var_name
        EXECUTE(str)
        str = var_name & " = var_value"
        EXECUTE(str)
    NEXT
```

This doesn't make sense to me, and those two `EXECUTE` statements seem to be begging for an injection attack (though I have not yet taken the time to construct one).

Is there a more canonical and secure method of parsing a query string for ASP Classic?

Comment: They are trying to encode dangerous characters in the query string.  The EXECUTE does look frightening.  I'm not a classic ASP programmer, but the way I would expect to see the code written is looping through the query parameters and validating that the key/value pairs only contain characters in {a-z,A-Z,0-9}.

Comment: @TheGreatContini - I should add that I can't (I don't think) use a character whitelist, because I have to support multi-language parameters.  Also, just because this was done doesn't mean it was correct or necessary.  For all I know, IIS already encodes things correctly....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the values in local variables (i.e. `Dim`) and exposing yourself to the vulnerabilities of `execute`, you can could store the values in a Dictionary.  You could encode the values taken from the querystring as you add them, but here is the skinny version.

```
set qs = server.createObject("scripting.dictionary")

for each q in request.querystring
    if not qs.exists(q) then qs.add q, request.querystring(q)
next
```